# pipe-lining the read instructions

Tags: c, pipeline, cpu-architecture

I read one of the questions on SO where the OP had following code

```
int main(){
    long long int  i;
    long int j;
    int k;
    scanf("%lld %ld %d",&i,&j,&k);
    return 0;
}
```

And was wondering if long long int or long int will be saved first. My question is different, therefore I am opening a new one, instead of spamming OP's question. Putting aside long int vs int idea, since a long int might require two memory fetch for load/store, if it is only int vs int, and scanf scans all the values and then store, considering if we have 3 pipeline stages on the architecture I am working on, wouldnt all the values be stored in one cycle? Someone did point out that these instructions will not overlap, but I cannot find any reasonable online source which clears that.

Comment: On most C implementations, `long` is still a single machine word (i.e. one load / store op.)  e.g. most 32bit machines have 32bit `long`.  If there is a 64bit type, it will be `long long`, not `long`.  Also, `scanf` will store the results one at a time.  There's no sane way for it to keep the first value around in a register until it's done converting the 3rd value.  It will just iterate over the format string, finishing one conversion before doing the next.

Comment: This question wouldn't be ridiculous if you were asking about a simple function that took a fixed number of args, like `void foo(long long *pi, long *pj, int *pk) { *pi = 1; *pj = 2; *pk = 3; }`.  Here it is, [compiled for 32bit ARM](http://goo.gl/SW98lL) by gcc 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

Discussing pipeline stages around a call to `scanf` is amazing! It is a bit like clearing a barn full of straw with a pair of tweezers, or driving a truck while looking at the road through a microscope.

`scanf()` has to perform so many checks and tests to implement the specification, that the minute details of the final storing into the result variables are completely irrelevant to the overall performance of this line of code (or lack thereof).

Comment: i absolutely agree with your formal argument. Since it has to do so much, the last step of storing does seem irrelevant. The angle that I am trying to understand here is, since pointers are passed to scanf, does this affect the decision to pipeline the stores?

Comment: Wouldnt compiler be smart enough to see that all the stores are in different memory locations, so all of them can be executed together, instead of doing it one by one

Comment: The function executes hundreds of instructions between any 2 of these conversions, values are most likely stored as they are parsed, pipelining is irrelevant.

Comment: No. The scanf function is a complex function - it is highly unlikely to be inlined. Instead, the four pointers (format plus 3 buffers) are put on the stack, a call is made, and when the call returns the three buffers have been filled.

Comment: More importantly, scanf is a varargs function, so its implementation is just going to loop over the format string.  It's not going to overlap conversions and end up with multiple results to store at the same time.

Comment: @PeterCordes: modern compilers are clever enough to convert `printf("%c", c)` into a single call `putchar(c)`, but I agree that `scanf` will resist such optimizations for a while and even if it were inlined, so many instructions would still be executed between stores as to make pipelining considerations moot.